# Perusal of code before running on live database

Tags: mysql, archive, sql-delete

I have a client with an unwieldy database that needs clearing down asap. I've done all the testing I can without impacting the performance of his database server, but as we're talking millions of records that need to be moved/deleted I can't easily create a test environment.

Here is the code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('set_time_limit', '0');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');


/* 
* Main Database Maint. 
*/

//connect to db
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=xxxxxx;dbname=xxxxx;charset=utf8', 'xxxx', 'xxxxxx');

// move listings to archive if over 1 month old
print "Copying items older than 1 month to archive\n";
$db->query("INSERT INTO `listing_archived` SELECT * FROM `listing` WHERE `dateadd` < DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)");

// delete listings from main database that meet same criteria
print "Deleting items from main database\n";
$db->query("DELETE FROM `listing` WHERE `dateadd` < DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)");

// optimize the table as we are expecting lots of deletes
print "Optimizing main database table\n";
$db->query("OPTIMIZE TABLE `listing`");


/*
* Archive database maint.
*/

// Select anything older than 3 months from archive table
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `listing_archive` WHERE `dateadd` < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)");

while ($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    //unlink images related to this item
    print "Deleting images linked to item {$r['id']}\n";


    // delete item from database
    print "Deleting database record {$r['id']}\n";  
    $db->query("DELETE FROM listing_archive WHERE id = {$r['id']}");
}
```

The comments should give you an idea of what is required. Items older than 1month in the listing table need to be moved to listing_archive. Then archived listings older than 3 months need deleting entirely.

I think I've done it the most robust way possible, but I'm open to critique if I've missed anything?

Comment: Just do a `mysqldump` and import it to another database and test your queries there. Better to have it and not need it than need it and not have it. If the database is that large then only backup the required tables.

Comment: The situation is a little more complex than I'm letting on. Basically the client has a few hundred MB's left on his database server, and a 50GB database. I would pipe the database straight to my dev server, but he is in the US and i'm in the UK so it keeps bombing out.

Comment: I should probably add that the listing_archive table is compressed and I'm probably going to limit the inserts/deletes to 100,000 records a time so I don't double up on too much data before deleting from the main table.